# Highchart React not rendering heat map after refresh its throwing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, hasownproperty

Import statement for high charts :

```
// Import Highcharts
   import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
   import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
   import HighchartsHeatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
// Load Highmaps as a module
    HighchartsHeatmap(Highcharts);
```

In the render I am using the below component

```
 <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} />
```

On the initial render i am getting output where as after i do manual refresh i am facing the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-6evf4

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsHeatmap from "highcharts/modules/heatmap";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

HighchartsHeatmap(Highcharts);
```